# Prometheus remote read influxdb

Tags: influxdb, prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus but familiar with Influx (currently running 1.6).

My understanding is it's possible to configure Prometheus to remotely read data from influx with the following configuration in prometheus.yml:

```
remote_read:
  url: "http://localhost:8086/api/v1/prom/read?db=bulkstats"
```

"bulkstats" is the database I'm trying to read data from in Prometheus. An example query that would work in influx would be:

```
SELECT "sess-curaaaactive" FROM "PDSNSYSTEM1" WHERE ("Nodename" = 'ALPRGAGQPNC') AND time >= now() - 6h"
```

However I cannot find one example of how to query that data from PromQL. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/supported_protocols/prometheus#how-prometheus-metrics-are-parsed-in-influxdb) is the link which matches prometheus format with influxdb's one.

In terms of prometheus's jargon, in your example, `sess-curaaaactive` is the metric name (measurement in influx) and `("Nodename" = 'ALPRGAGQPNC')` is just a label which prometheus attaches to the measurement to create a time series.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was looking for an equivalent PromQL query but ended up using a different method.

Comment: @musca999 Sorry for asking but I'm having the exact same problem as you... How did you managed to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Ale I never solved it. Just didn't use Prometheus.

Comment: @musca999 Wow hahaha and what did you use?